# Counting non empty elements of array

Tags: c++, arrays, visual-studio-2010, sizeof

I need method, that return numbers of non empty elements of array of `ints`. `sizeof(arr)/sizeof(type)`, like below:

```
   int table[255]={1,2,3,'a','b'};
   cout << "size of: " << sizeof(table)/sizeof(int) <<  endl;
```

returns `255`, but I need to count elements so the result will be `5`.
Shall I make my own `while loop` or is there any embedded function (I use Visual Studio 2010)?

Comment: What is the condition that indicates "is empty", is it `table[i] == 0`?

Comment: Create your own `while` loop

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that a non-empty element for `T array[N] = {};` is the one that is default-initialized - `T t{};`, the answer is: yes, there is a standard algorithm for counting elements that match a given pattern, or satisfy a given condition, which is [std::count](http://cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/count)

```
// include header file where the algorithm is defined:
#include <algorithm>

// use std::count to count 0 elements, which is a default value all elements
// are initialized with for int tab[N] = {};
// and subtract this value from the total number of elements of array
int howMany = 255 - std::count(table, table + 255, 0);

// table and table+255 specify the ranges the algorithm operate on
```

Comment: I think it would be more helpful for the OP and further visitors, when you add some explaination to your intension.

Comment: @reporter: added explanation

Answer (score 0):

If you are using C++, why not using C++ containers like `std::vector` and use `<algorithm>` ?

Anyway, `sizeof()` will ALWAYS return 255 * sizeof(int) here because the table will contains 255 ints in memory.

Answer (score 0):

**8.5.1.7**
If there are fewer initializer-clauses in the list than there are members in the aggregate, then each member
not explicitly initialized shall be initialized from an empty initializer list. For int, expression of the form int(),that is, 0.

You could use std::count from algorithm but there is one issue

```
int table[255]={1,0 <<< this value were stetted by user and it is not an 'empty',3,'a','b'};
```

So how to distinct 0 assigned by default initializer and 0 that comes as actual value? As a solution you probably should use some INVALID_VALUE definition to set values for elements in your array because 0 is not a greatest choice to mark value as unassigned. And init your array as

```
memset(table, INVALID_VALUE, table_size);
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be done by writing own function's template, like this:

```
template<typename It>
unsigned count_non_val(It first, It last, const decltype(*first)& val){
    unsigned result=0;
    for(It i=first; i!=last; ++i)
        if(*i!=val)
            ++result;
    return result;
}
```

//Usage:

```
std::cout<<count_non_val(table, table+255, 0)<<'\n';
```